# Android don't go to new line

Tags: android

I have a custom `EditText` and I think it doesn't matter. It also has setted 
`setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` and it is multiline.
How could I avoid user clicking enter and the line goes to next. 
I think `TextWatcher` isn't capable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchbox"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
 >
</EditText>

//i know singleLine  is deprecated, but it's the best one for you and modify accordingly
```

Answer (score 2):

@Androider: Yeah .`singleLine` is deprecated . Just set `android:maxLines="1"`

```
  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchbox"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
 />
```